# Apache Spark nested tree aggregation

Tags: java, mysql, join, apache-spark, nested-sets

Here is the base SQL query:

```
SELECT
   child.ID
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(ancestor.title ORDER BY ancestor.LEFT ASC SEPARATOR ' / ') as path

FROM my_nested_table child

  JOIN my_nested_table ancestor
    ON    child.LEFT >= ancestor.LEFT
      AND child.RIGHT <= ancestor.RIGHT

GROUP BY
  child.LEFT

ORDER BY
  child.LEFT;
```

To do so I'm thinking about **filtering the cartesian product child and ancestor RDDs** build as follow.

```
JavaRDD<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, GenericRecord>> mapChild    =    child.map(r -> new Tuple3<>((Integer) r.get("LEFT"), (Integer) r.get("RIGHT"), r));
JavaRDD<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, GenericRecord>> mapAncestor = ancestor.map(r -> new Tuple3<>((Integer) r.get("LEFT"), (Integer) r.get("RIGHT"), r));
```

Is there a better way to do it with Apache Spark 1.6?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: This solution ain't work, a free-form MySQL query run by Apache Sqoop did the trick.

Comment: I'll also try to broadcast collected RDD as map.